# Unble to Extract the _body response in angular 4 in JSON format

Tags: json, angular, angular4-httpclient

I am using angular 4.2.6 for my application. I have a service like this

```js
checkStaff(email: any) {

  return this._http.post(this.url + "/Impsapi/getStaff", JSON.stringify(email)).map(
    (resp) => resp
  )

}
```

checkStaff(email:any){
     return 
    this._http.post(this.url+"/Impsapi/getStaff",JSON.stringify(email)).map(
      (resp)=> resp
    )

}

```js
this.loginServ.checkStaff(this.user)
  .subscribe(
    userData => {
      this._return = userData;
      console.log(this._return);
    }
  );
```

The Server returns JSON as response. but when i log the output, i get the below
[logged response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuCQ5.png)

please I need to consume the data in the body of the response. I have not been able convert the ._body to a proper json and use for the app. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my problem solved. My PHP is hosted on wampserver. In a way invalid JSON is always returned when i make call to the server. I had to use the `ob_clean()` function and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The response data are in `JSON` string form. The app must parse that string into JavaScript objects by calling `res.json()`.

```
return this._http.post(this.url + "/Impsapi/getStaff", JSON.stringify(email)).map(
    (resp) => resp.json()
  )
```

**Update** 
try following code snippet

```
checkStaff(email: any) {
    return this._http.post(this.url + "/Impsapi/getStaff", JSON.stringify(email))
    .map(res => {return res.json()})


  }
```

Comment: I have done this severally, but i get   "ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)"

Comment: @valentine  What you get ?

Comment: @valentine then try `.text() `

Comment: i tried that too. it returns only the body very well but as string. and JSON.parse doesn't work on it

Comment: If you are not able to apply JSON.parse() it means your service is not returning proper json response

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.loginServ.checkStaff(this.user)
  .subscribe(
    userData => {
      this._return = userData.json();
      console.log(this._return);
    }
  );
```

I mean your checkStaff:

```
checkStaff(email: any): Observable<Response> {

  return this._http.post(this.url + "/Impsapi/getStaff", JSON.stringify(email));

}


export classMyResp
{
id: string;
 /*so on...*/
}
```

This will give you the body of response If there is any.

Comment: Also there is no need for '.map( (resp)=> resp )' in your code. just make sure you are returning an Observable<Response> in checkStaff method

Comment: ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: i removed the map and added .text(). i get [{"id":"3","staffName":"Chucks Akinudo","email":"chucka.akinudo@","role":"admin","department":"admin","staffid":"G040"}]. as response. how do i convert this to JSON. or how do i access the values

Comment: Then its the response which is coming is having the problem.

Comment: Ok for that to happen, your this._return should be mapping with your JSON response. Create an object of the type your response is, and you are good to go

Comment: Updated Above response,

Comment: so i made the _return to be object type. but when i try to assign the value of the response, it says string is not assignable to an object. and i am unable to use .json to convert the response to JSON

Comment: yes because you have to keep it as an Object not as String. change it to Object and check. Can you post the updated codes

Comment: nothing seems to work. i am using json_encode from PHP(server side) to convert to json.  i am a bit confuse. is it angular 4.2 or typescript?? really confuse.. i finally end up with an array like this.   ["[{"id":"3","staffName":"Chucks Akinudo","email":"fdkf":"admin","department":"admin","staffid":"GA040"}]"] but i can parse it...i have tried

Comment: It looks like a list of data

Comment: Can you share your PHP code where you are encoding the Data??

Comment: $response = [];
    $data= json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $email = $data->email;
    $response= json_encode($this->Login->getstaff($email));
    print_r($response);

Comment: It makes sense now, you are having Object within object... The first Object which you get at angular UI IS A 'Login' object, which internally contains 'email' object. Since there are two different objects involved, in Angular too you have to first read response in and Login object, which internally contains your Email object